# Returning a string given a particular integer input

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc

I'm attempting to learn Haskell and while trying to write a simple function I have come across a problem. Using the following code:

```
squarenumber x = if x<10
                then x^2
                else return "Input is too large, please input a value less than 10."
```

The issue seems to be with the `else` portion of the function. How can I amend this function such that it will return a string if the input is greater than 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do what you want. In Haskell an expression should have the same type. It should not be `Integer` at some circumstances and `String` at some other circumstances. But what you want can be achived using an `Either` data type:

```
squarenumber :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Either String a
squarenumber x = if x < 10
                 then Right (x^2)
                 else Left $ "Input is too large, please input a value less than 10."
```

Also you are confusing the Haskell's `return` with imperative language one. Note that in Haskell `return` has a completly different meaning. It is one of the methods of Monad typeclass.